# Delete all instances of a value in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to delete all instances of a value in a numpy array which is shaped in rows.

```
a = array([5,1,2,4,9,2]).reshape(-1, 1)
print("before delete", a)
a = np.delete(a, np.where(a == 2))
print("after delete", a)
```

The output is

```
before delete [[5]
 [1]
 [2]
 [4]
 [9]
 [2]]
after delete [1 4 9]
```

I don't know why 5 is deleted. I expect to see

```
[[5]
 [1]
 [4]
 [9]]
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you look at `np.where(a==2)`?  And check its format with the `np.delete` docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` in this case returns 2 arrays. The first one is the indexes of the values that are equal to `2`, but the second is not needed. You need to grab the first one:

```
a = np.delete(a, np.where(a == 2)[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array([5, 1, 4, 9])
```

Comment: What you wrote is the one I wrote. So why your output is something else?

Comment: @mahmood I think richardec did a wrong copy paste, the explanation was correct. Check the update.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, @mozway is correct. I mistakenly omitted the `[0]` which mozway fixed for me. Thank you @mozway!

Comment: Btw, I wouldn't call the second array "junk" this is just the indices on the second dimension. Not necessary here, but not "junk" ;)